# Console application scheduled using task scheduler or Windows service fro long running processes

Tags: .net, windows-services, console-application, windows-task-scheduler

We have the following functionalities which we are not sure if it is better to run as Console application scheduled using windows task scheduler or as Windows service:-

1. Users upload files inside SharePoint document libraries
2. The service (either console app or windows service) need to read the files using SharePoint CSOM code >> send the file to a 3rd  party application using Rest API >> get the data from the 3rd party API and update SharePoint using CSOM code >> move the related file to a different SharePoint document library

So we are not sure if we should implement the above as Console application scheduled using task scheduler or as Windows service?

We have the following facts:-

1. Our hosting server is a windows VM hosted inside AWS.
2. We do not want 2 executions to run at the same time, this to prevent 2 executions from working on the same files.
3. our code must be in C#.

So can anyone advice if we should go with Console application scheduled using task scheduler or as Windows service and Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your main concern is to prevent one instance of the app (or a thread) from processing a file already being processed by another instance (or another thread), then you can use a system synchronization primitive (see [Mutex Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=net-5.0)) to implement this. (Just be sure to use a try/finally block to release the Mutex.)

WRT console app vs. Windows service, the choice really comes down to style and/or preference (and perhaps other requirements unknown here)

###### A console app

- Is simpler to code
- Can use Mutex to control synchronization, or an external control structure (db, log, etc.)
- But it has to rely on an external scheduler for execution
- And it may need to rely on the scheduler to handle re-executing failed jobs

###### A Windows service

- Is less simple to code
- Can use a Mutex for synchronization, but also other internal or external control structures
- It can manage its own schedule
- And may be simpler for implementing complex failed-job handling logic

P.S. One unique feature of the Task Scheduler is its ability to wake the system up from hibernation/sleep to execute a job, although that's unlikely to be of much interest in your AWS hosted VM environment.